# How to get the complete list of .as/.mxml file compiled into the final swf of a flex project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I'm using **Adobe Flex Builder3**,

and now my final swf is too big,

so I want to check if any unnecessary files are compiled into the target..

Answer (score 2):

The flex compiler can generate a link report xml file.
Use compiler args to create that file and analyze it. There some nice apps out there who can interpret the xml and tell you what it;s in use etc.

Search for  "link-report" here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html

Comment: @fms the compiler option is:  << -link-report filename.xml  >>  If your file is named build.xml then this is it. :))